# Access LoggerFilterOptions from custom ILogger

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When adding logging to DI service collection in MVC Core by calling AddLogging it is common to load "Logging" section from appsettings/configuration and pass it on to ILogOptionsBuilder.AddConfiguration like this:

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging(config => {
    config.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    config.AddConsole();
    config.AddDebug();
    config.AddProvider(new MyCustomLoggerFactory());
});
```

The info passed on to AddConfiguration configures a LoggerFilterOptions object which both Debug logger and Console logger accesses to determine actual loglevel.

Is it possible for me to access that info object from my ILogger created from my MyCustomLoggerFactory or do I have to pass another copy of the configuration section to MyCustomLoggerFactory and manually parse the section?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency inject `IOptions<LoggerFilterOptions>`. An example is available at http://jackhiston.com/2017/7/30/using-iconfigureoptionst/ .

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.